# How to Parallel y deploy two packages using Quick Deploy option

Tags: deployment, release, deployment-api, quick-deploy

I am having Two packages for every release to the production before the deployment window i validate them successfully with Prod to keep them ready for deployment, I what to see the Quick deploy option for both successful validated packages but know i was able to see only for the last validated package.

There is any way to have Quick deploy option for both packages? so that i can run them at the same deployment window.

Appreciate for any solution for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Quick Deploy only applies for one package at a time. This is because one package could invalidate the other. You would need to create a new package that contains the contents of both and upload that one instead.

Comment: would creating / converting those 2 packages into unlocked packages solve this challenge by doing parallel installation at the same time ? sorry this needs to be raised as separate question I am not stackex expert