# Validation of two packages at the same time, but only quick deploying one. Possible?

Tags: deployment, validation, package

Pretty simple question here. Can I validate 2 packages at the same time, and only choose 1 to quick deploy?

background here is we have a release tomorrow and the package is already validated (takes ~5 hours to validate). But we just discovered a defect from our last release, and may need to release that tomorrow first (also ~5 hours to validate)

So being able to validate multiple packages and choosing which one to deploy is what im looking for. I know once one package is deployed the quick deploy functionality will be lost for the other validated packages.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Parallel y deploy two packages using Quick Deploy option](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181122/how-to-parallel-y-deploy-two-packages-using-quick-deploy-option)

Comment: I don't believe the behavior has changed since 2017 when that answer was written but wanted to link it here, quick deploy only works with a single package in scope at a time.

Comment: @MarkPond No, but we can now recommend a better way.

Comment: @MarkPond It kind of does kind of doesn't. I saw that post before I posted but was still confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only Quick Deploy the last successful Validation. In the future, I recommend that you look into using Unlocked Packages. Unlike deployments, [Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm) validate during the [Promotion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_create_pkg_ver_promote.htm) process, so installing typically only takes a few minutes, just as any AppExchange package would take. Note that you cannot take advantage of this behavior if you create an [Org-Dependent Unlocked Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_org_dependent.htm).

Comment: Worth also explicitly stating this behaviour does not apply to Org Dependent Unlocked Packages which perform validation during installation. IIRC.

Comment: @PhilW Yeah, just checked the docs. Org-Dependent UPs validate during install.